# Apply subsetting or row deleting function columnwise, based on grouping

Tags: r, subset

Some sample data frame (real data has 500k observations by 20 variables):

```
set.seed(1)
dataframe <- data.frame()
IDs <- as.factor(sample(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 3)], prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5), 1000, replace = TRUE))
Var1 <- sample(x = c(20:1500), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
Var2 <- sample(x = c(1:15), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
Var3 <- sample(x = c(0.1:8.5), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
Var4<- sample(x = c(12:255), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
Var5 <- sample(x = c(14000000:15000000), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
dataframe <- data.frame(IDs, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)
dataframe$Var5 <- as.POSIXlt(dataframe$Var5, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

For every subject in `ID`, I want to remove all rows for which `Var1` are not within the range of (mean +/- 0.5 standard deviation) in Var1.

I guess the way to go is to use `dplyr`, pipe `dataframe` to `group_by(ID)`, and apply a function. If so, I need help with both the function and dplyr commands.

My first attempt was to use a for loop with ID:

```
for(ID in levels(dataframe$IDs)){
  # Get 0.5 standard deviations
  sd05 <- sd(dataframe[which(dataframe$IDs == ID), "Var1"]) * 0.5
  # Get mean for subsetting
  mean_for_subset <- mean(dataframe[which(dataframe$IDs == ID), "Var1"])
  dataframe[which( dataframe[which(dataframe$IDs == ID), "Var1"] > (mean_for_subset + sd05)
    & dataframe[which(dataframe$IDs == ID), "Var1"] < (mean_for_subset - sd05))
            ,] <- NULL
}
```

That gives warnings as is.na() was not applied to vector or list and `dataframe` still has 1000 observations.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please show your attempt. Perhaps you could show exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I edited my opening post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dataframe <- data.table(dataframe)
meanV1 <- dataframe[, mean(Var1)]
sdV1 <- 0.5 * dataframe[, sd(Var1)]
dataframe <- dataframe[Var1 < meanV1 + sdV1 & Var1 > meanV1 - sdV1]
```

Of if this is to be done by ID:

```
library(data.table)
dataframe <- data.table(dataframe)
dataframe[, c("mean1", "sd1") := list(mean(Var1), 0.5 * sd(Var1)), by = IDs]
dataframe <- dataframe[Var1 < mean1 + sd1 & Var1 > mean1 - sd1]
```

Then to remove the new rows:

```
dataframe[, c("mean1", "sd1") := NULL]
```

---

Done on two columns:

```
library(data.table)
dataframe <- data.table(dataframe)
dataframe[, c(
  "mean1",
  "sd1",
  "mean2",
  "sd2"
) := list(
  mean(Var1),
  0.5 * sd(Var1)),
  mean(Var2),
  0.5 * sd(Var2)),
  by = IDs
]

dataframe <- dataframe[
  Var1 < mean1 + sd1 &
  Var1 > mean1 - sd1 &
  Var2 < mean2 + sd2 &
  Var2 > mean2 - sd2
]

dataframe[, c("mean1", "sd1", "mean2", "sd2") := NULL]
```

Comment: Standard deviation should be computed separately per ID, I guess. Maybe something like `DT[, .SD[Var1 %between% (mean(Var1) + c(-.5,5)*sd(Var1))], by=ID]`

Comment: I may be wrong, but wouldn't using your method become slow on larger datasets compared to preinstantiating the means and sd's in their own column?

Comment: Because I'm neurotic, I double checked. On this data set, the prior answer runs in a mean of 2.389 ms while the latter solution in 27.432 ms. Wouldn't matter much until you got into large data sets, but worth showing empirically!

Comment: @Quant18, thank you, that immediately helped. Do you think it is possible to extend that operation to `Var2` and `Var3` as well, without using a for loop?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my original answer. I did it for var2, see if you can extend it to var3.

Comment: Thanks again.
Semi off-topic:
To get a more general solution, can these methods be "vectorized" as in applying a function to a variable number of columns? I did not see a general approach to apply a function that modifies and subsets data in-place; am I looking for the wrong key words?

Comment: It could. If you melt() the data first, so that you have a "long" dataset where one column is called "variable" and the consituents are Var1, Var2, etc, data.table provides some really convenient ways of working with it from there on out. Basically, instead of doing by = ID's like I did, you would then do, by = c("IDs", "variable"). Look into the melt function, it can save you a lot of verbosity. It might, in practice, look like melt(dataframe, id.vars = "IDs"), but I'll let you dig in.